# C++ how to synthesize and align time-series intervals?

Tags: c++, time-series, intervals

Working in C++ I have some time-series data generated at one second intervals like so:

```
Data begins;
2014 Dec 14 13:59:57   8.7
2014 Dec 14 13:59:58   6.6
2014 Dec 14 13:59:59   2.1
2014 Dec 14 14:00:00   0.5
2014 Dec 14 14:00:01   2.3
2014 Dec 14 14:00:02   3.5
2014 Dec 14 14:00:04   1.0 <--- Intentional gap; could be that no data is generated in a given second
2014 Dec 14 14:00:05   7.3
2014 Dec 14 14:00:06   4.8
and so on ........
```

The time stamps are of `boost::posix_time::ptime` type.

I would like to take this data and synthesize from it time-series data of larger intervals for example of 2, 5, 10 seconds or any other whole multiple.

The value associated with any given interval would be the mean value from that prior number of seconds.

So the first 2 second interval time-series value would be the mean of;

```
2014 Dec 14 13:59:57   8.7
2014 Dec 14 13:59:58   6.6
```

and would itself be;

```
2014 Dec 14 13:59:58   7.7 <-- first synthesized 2 second interval time-series data element.
```

Now, the original source data series could commence at any time.  I would like to make it such that the synthesized time-series intervals will align with their natural whole multiples and natural points in time.

So the first 5 second interval data element would be the mean of ONLY four prior 1 second data elements:

```
2014 Dec 14 13:59:57   8.7
2014 Dec 14 13:59:58   6.6
2014 Dec 14 13:59:59   2.1
2014 Dec 14 14:00:00   0.5
```

to give:

```
2014 Dec 14 14:00:00   4.5 <--- first synthesized 5 second interval time-series data element.
```

and at the natural turn of the minute and hour a new 5 second accumulation would begin at:

```
 2014 Dec 14 14:00:01   2.3
```

It would take the values;

```
2014 Dec 14 14:00:01   2.3
2014 Dec 14 14:00:02   3.5
2014 Dec 14 14:00:04   1.0 <--- Intentional gap; could be that no data is generated in a given second
2014 Dec 14 14:00:05   7.3
```

and synthesize them into:

```
2014 Dec 14 14:00:05   3.5 <---- Aligned second synthesized 5 second interval time-series data element.
```

It's my first time trying this so I'd like to ask for suggestions of open-source libraries which perform this kind of functionality or approaches which I could employ to achieve the aim of synthesizing higher interval time-series in C++?

Comment: You cannot ask for suggestions of open-source libraries, it is offtopic here.

Comment: I have a nearly identical problem on my hands. The granularity is higher in my case. Would like you to clarify the meaning of "alignment" that you are looking for.

Comment: @KalyanS To clarify on alignment; say if synthesizing a 2 second time-series then the timestamps of the synthesized data would be on 2, 4, 6, 8 .... etc seconds past the minute or if a 5 second interval the time stamps would be 5, 10, 15, 20 ....... etc seconds past the minute. Ideally would also like to program it to accept a base series of other intervals eg. 1min, 1 hour, 1 day etc. and synthesize higher intervals from them.

Comment: I have enough incentive to answer the question for both of us. Am looking at nearly the same problem, then, with some warping allowed.

Comment: @KalyanS Is the 'warping' to allow for situations where the synthesized interval does not fit neatly into the concept of a minute (or other time period); e.g. a 7 second synthesized time-series interval (60 / 7 = 8.571) would follow the pattern; 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63.